# counifs Excel to Python Formula

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Excel formula 
`=countif(C:L,"<=100" , C:L,">0")`

Trying to count cells where it's value <=100 and is >0 (or != 0)

I was able to get somewhere near using iloc to group columns, then filter as following, then count, but seems I'm getting into deep mud, so here I am x(

`columns=(filteredbyABArank.iloc[:, [2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]]<=100) & (filteredbyABArank.iloc[:, [2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]]>0)`

`columns.count()`

The only way found was using a for loop, and doing it one row at a time, As there is no easy way to do "countif" on python, but using forloop

Comment: You want to count all cells in the dataframe, or just for specific columns?

Comment: Usually something like `((df > 0) & (df <= 100)).sum()` can already work. Since the combined boolean expression will yield a dataframe of the same shape, but just with True/False values, the sum (over columns *and* rows) will give the total count.

Comment: I'm looking to specify the columns which in my case is 10 columns and not the entire dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an np.select() to find where the column is >0 or <= 100

```
condition_list = [(df['Column2'] > 0) & (df['Column2'] <= 100)]
choice_list = [1]
df['Count Column'] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, 0)
print(df['Count Column'].sum())
```

Seeing your updated question I see you want to target 10 columns specifically. You can use this updated option with the np.select() to make it more dynamic and expandable

```
column_list = ['Column1', 'Column2']
for i in range(0, len(column_list)):
    condition_list = [(df[column_list[i]] > 0) & (df[column_list[i]] <= 100)]
    choice_list = [1]
    new_column__count = f'Count Column {column_list[i]}'
    df[new_column__count] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, 0)
df
```

Comment: that worked on 1 column, and would return an error if tried to adjust it to 10 columns  <br> `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 10, placement implies 1` <br>
`(Word,4,50,200,5,0,0,651,32,101,100,Word,Word)`
I tried [['Column2','Column3'....etc]] but couldn't make it work on several columns

Comment: I can look at it again, but would you mind updating your post to include programable code? This worked on my sample data I made, so I would need to work with a sample of what your working with to adjust it to work differently.